# how to know the actual downloads of an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, download, itunes-store

i recently submitted an app and it's ready for sale now.But day by day i'm getting curious about the number of downloads,in android market(google play)it is already provided and  user can see the number of downloads,is there any possible way to know about the actual downloads ?

Edit:i have researched other answers and haven't got an accurate answer.i even looked in to te sales and trends of itunes connect but i'm not able to figure actual number of downloads.all the downloads were from same id and most of my friends has downloaded it.so i'm asking is there is any reliable source to know about actual no of downloads

Comment: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/

Comment: Google admob may be the way, https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

Comment: i checked the sales and trends in itunes connect but i'm not sure they are showing accurate data.about 50 of my friends told me they have downloaded it and sales and trends shows  10 downloads all from same id ,so i'm getting confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard of a website called appfigures. It links your apple itunesconnect account to thier website(your account) and they generate reports. Just try that website and see..

http://www.appfigures.com/

Comment: thanks a lot whysoserius,it worked